# Multiple delimiters

Tags: c++, delimiter

i have an input from a file with multiple delimiters for example

```
years,(7),(9)
years,(8),(3)
```

what methods can i use to separate them as

```
years
7
9
years
8
3
```

i tried to use strok but i gt nothing displayed with the following.

```
getline (myfile,line, ',' );
line = strtok (pch," (),");
```

i got this example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: From your example I would replace all "," with line breaks "\r\n" or "\n".

Comment: Did you just mix of `line` and `pch` in your example code block? Cos you read data into `line` using `getline`, and then you overwrite it immediately with the output of `strtok` instead of passing it _in_ to `strtok`.

Comment: opps. Thanks alot for pointing out. i retried but i got an error cannot convert strd::string to char*. Sorry im not really gd with the errors.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [std::locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) and his trusty sidekick [imbue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue):

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>


struct punct_ctype : std::ctype<char> {
  punct_ctype() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
  static mask const* get_table()
  {
    static mask rc[table_size];
    rc[' '] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc['('] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc[')'] = std::ctype_base::space;
    rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
    return &rc[0];
  }
};

int main() {
  using std::string;
  using std::cin;
  using std::locale;

  cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new punct_ctype));

  string word;
  while(cin >> word) {
    std::cout << word << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do you mind explaining the codes? im not very gd with std. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `strtok` right:

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char * pch;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
while (pch != NULL)
{
  printf ("%s\n",pch);
  pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/ for more information.